# How to store file into another server liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I want to store file into another server in liferay.

By default liferay stores file in data/document_library folder on the same server where liferay is installed.

But, I want to store file in another server.

E.g.: Ip `x.x.x.x/test_folder`

I tried following, but didn't work
I overwrite property in `portal-ext.properties`

```
dl.store.impl = com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.AdvancedFileSystemStore
dl.store.file.system.root.dir =////103.XXX.XX.XXX//test_folder
```

How can I achieve this in liferay?

Comment: Whick OS are you using? Windows? Are you trying to use a windows network folder path?

Comment: no.. I am using  ubantu

Comment: Have you tried mounting the network folder? You could try the solution in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240045/how-to-mount-network-folder-in-ubuntu-12-04.
Make sure the network folder supports file-locking to avoid corruption.

Comment: From portal.properties: #
    # Characters that are not allowed in directory names and file names.
    #
    dl.char.blacklist=\\\\,//,:,*,?,\",<,>,|,../,/..  You have // in your directory path. Might try removing // from the DL Character Blacklist..

Comment: @RussBohl The `dl.char.blacklist` is for file and folder names in the CMS - not for any path in the `portal-ext.properties` (that would make no sense anyway, as a _path_ needs `/` characters)